# Remove item from session info

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I am writing this project with `CodeIgniter`, where you can add and remove items from your bucket, like an internet shop.

I have an array inside my session class, what I'm trying to do is to search the elements by id and remove them.

```
public function removeRow($id) {
    if ($id) {
        $bucket = $this->session->userdata('bucket');
        foreach ($bucket as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['id'] == $id) {
                unset($bucket[$key]);
            }
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata(array(
            'bucket' => $bucket
                )
        );
    }
```

and the `session` information:

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => e0c6303a7c24a05436ef0abfe2424c44
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
    [last_activity] => 1363718778
    [user_data] => 
    [a] => test
    [bucket] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Maksas Frajus - AmÅ¾inybÄ—s glÄ—byje
                            [price] => 30.99
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Maksas Frajus - AtÄ—jÅ«nas
                            [price] => 35.99
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Maksas Frajus - Paprasti stebuklingi daiktai
                            [price] => 27.5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

i get this error message :

```
Message: Undefined index: id
```

and i don't even know what I'm doing wrong. could someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($value['id'] == $id) {
```

should be this:

```
if ($value[0]['id'] == $id) {
```

You have a nested array so you need to go one level deeper.

---

Example Array per comment below:

```
[bucket] => Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => Maksas Frajus - AmÅ¾inybÄ—s glÄ—byje
                [price] => 30.99
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Maksas Frajus - AtÄ—jÅ«nas
                [price] => 35.99
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Maksas Frajus - Paprasti stebuklingi daiktai
                [price] => 27.5
            )

    )
```

Comment: Looking at your array, I don't see why you have the extra levels. Your array should be in the format I have shown above. Then doing a simple `if (isset($bucket[$id])) {unset($bucket[$id]);}` would suffice without needing to loop through the array.